# Stop Fargate Task when my typescript function has completed

Tags: typescript, lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I migrated a lambda script to fargate. The task is created and started via a scheduler. Once my code has finished its task which involves some queries to DynamoDB and writing files to S3 I would like the fargate task to stop.

I was under the assumption that this would just be the case following the flow above. Should I be expecting this or do I need something to explicitly stop the task from running?

I added some logging after I complete all my promises within the code and it looks like everything is good so I don't believe something is still waiting on that front.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Lambda, shutdown steps are initiated essentially once the steps defined in the handler are executed. However, ECS is simply running a container given to it. It has no idea whether the task is completed or not. As long as the process inside the container is running (ie the process given as the entrypoint), the ECS task will continue to run. So basically to stop the task you need to exit this process.